# Update method from the ajax call on django rest api?

Tags: ajax, django, django-rest-framework

There is a update view api made to update the content of employee. I can update from the django rest framework view.
I'm using jquery ajax to update but its not working.

```
$(document).ready(function(){
function getCookie(name) {
    var cookieValue = null;
    if (document.cookie && document.cookie !== '') {
        var cookies = document.cookie.split(';');
        for (var i = 0; i < cookies.length; i++) {
            var cookie = jQuery.trim(cookies[i]);
            // Does this cookie string begin with the name we want?
            if (cookie.substring(0, name.length + 1) === (name + '=')) {
                cookieValue = decodeURIComponent(cookie.substring(name.length + 1));
                break;
            }
        }
    }
    return cookieValue;
}

var csrftoken = getCookie('csrftoken');

function csrfSafeMethod(method) {
    // these HTTP methods do not require CSRF protection
    return (/^(GET|HEAD|OPTIONS|TRACE)$/.test(method));
}


$(".update-employee").submit(function(event){
      event.preventDefault()
      var this_ = $(this)
      var form =  this_.serializeArray()
      $.each(form, function(key, value){

      })
      var formData =  this_.serialize()
      console.log(formData);

var temp =
{
  "name": form[4].value,
  "email": form[1].value,
  "address": form[2].value,
  "phone_number": form[3].value,
  "username": {{ user_id }},
  "school": {{ school_id}},
  "language_id": {{ language_id }}
```

}

```
      $.ajax({
        url: "/api/student/{{ id }}",
        data: JSON.stringify(temp),
        beforeSend: function(xhr, settings) {
    if (!csrfSafeMethod(settings.type) && !this.crossDomain) {
        xhr.setRequestHeader("X-CSRFToken", csrftoken);
    }
  },

        method: "PUT",
        contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
        dataType: 'json',
        success: function(data){
           console.log(data)


        },
        error: function(data){
          console.log("error")
          console.log(data.statusText)
          console.log(data.status)
        }
      })

    });
    });
```

The temp variable uses the values to update which is sent through context data from views.
what is the problem here, its showing error in console.

Comment: I'm guessing that a method call in your beforeSend handler is throwing up an error. In particular the xhr.setRequest call.

Comment: What is the solution? Used same code for post method works.